# how to convert all int values to float?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

How can I instead now input float temperature values. At the moment I can only use int values or it crashes.

I have tried to change all int values to float but then it still doesnt work.

```
    import numpy

    # creates arrays of size 30
    midday_array = [i for i in range(30)]
    midnight_array = [i for i in range(30)]

    # loop through each day of the month
    # temperatures can only be between -10, 35
    for x in range(0, 30):
        value = int(input('The recorded Midday temp is: '))
        while value > 35 or value < -10:
            print('The temp must be between -20 and 45, sorry')
            value = int(input('The recorded Midday temp is: '))
        midday_array[x] = value
        value = int(input('The recorded Midnight temp is: '))
        while value > 35 or value < -10:
            print('The temp must be between -20 and 45, sorry')
            value = int(input('The recorded Midnight temp is: '))
        midnight_array[x] = value
    print('The midnight temperatures recorded are: ', midnight_array)
    print('The midday temperatures recorded are: ', midday_array)
    print('The Average Temperature from those recorded are: ', 
    (numpy.mean(midnight_array)))
    print('The Average Temperature from those recorded are: ', 
    (numpy.mean(midday_array)))
```

To allow me to input floats.

Answer (score 0):

> **Q** : *How can I instead now <sub>( `int`-s )</sub>  input float temperature values?*

### Let's start to "isolate" where the problem may appear

The **`numpy`**-part is out of the game, the **`.mean()`**-method can process either `int`-s, or `float`-s

```
>>> np.mean( [ 12,  13,  14,  15,  16 ] )
14.0
>>> np.mean( [ 12., 13., 14., 15., 16. ] )
14.0
```

**[Q.E.D.]**

---

The **`input()`**-part is working this way

```
>>> type( input( "Give me an int number, please. Thank you: " ) )
Give me an int number, please. Thank you: 123
<class 'str'>

>>> type( input( "Give me a float number, please. Thank you: " ) )
Give me a float number, please. Thank you: 123.456
<class 'str'>

>>> ####  +++++----------------------------------THIS IS A FORCED TYPE-CONVERSION
>>> ####  |||||
>>> ####  vvvvv
>>> ####  float(                                                       )
>>> ####  |||||
>>> ####  vvvvv
>>> type( float( input( "Give me an int number, please. Thank you: " ) ) )
Give me a float number, please. Thank you: 123.456
<class 'float'>
```

So the proper conversion from a `input()`-default-delivered string is a must.

Enjoy both the powers of NumPy & Python - worth learning for any your future work.